# <h:outputText> and other jsf tags not rendereing

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.6 with Hibernate 5 and JSF 2.2.

My application.properties file is as follows:

```
spring.application.name=BrokersWing
spring.mvc.date-format=DD/MM/YYYY


spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/brokerswing?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.jpa.show-sql=true    
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.session.store-type=none

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

My faces-config file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

    <application>
        <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

Also, in Web.xml i have configured Faces Context Servlet as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now when I use jsf `h:outputText` tag and try to output some text in the browser then nothing is happening. I run my application by click on Run => Spring Boot App.

When i inspected HTML in browser i saw that the tags did not convert and were present as we see in eclipse. [You can see the screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqLqY.png)

Please can you help me diagnose the issue and help me output the text

Comment: html tags? Or did you mean jsf tags? Read the top hits on https://www.google.com/search?q=not+rendered+jsf+stackoverflow

Comment: I mean Jsf tags

Comment: Important information: `com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler` is actually from Facelets 1.x. Get rid of it altogether. JSF 2.x already bundles its own Facelets 2.x implementation.

Comment: Hi Balusc. Thnx for that. But m still facing this issue. My JSF tags are not rendering. M stuck since 2 days. Btw have heard lot about you.